# Conv2Query not enabled due to current app not in whitelist Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Having this error on my log just when I enter my built-signed-and-released Ionic app. Any idea of how to fix this?

```
Ionic version - 3.19.1
Cordova version - 7.1.0
Node version - 8.9.3
```

Log:

```
02-21 11:13:00.335 2111-11520/? I/WindowManager: Switching to real app window: Window{d547428 u0 io.ionic.app/io.ionic.app.MainActivity}
02-21 11:13:00.437 2111-2156/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed io.ionic.app/.MainActivity: +1s64ms
02-21 11:13:08.903 2634-2634/? I/LatinIme: onActivate() : EditorInfo = Package = io.ionic.app : Type = Text : Learning = Disable : Suggestion = Hide : AutoCorrection = Disable : Microphone = Show : Incognito = Disable
02-21 11:13:08.986 2634-2634/? W/Conv2QueryExtension: Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [io.ionic.app] not in whitelist
```

Comment: I get the same message but for my Btle Scan operation ... and yes, I have given location permissions. This only happens on the Nexus 7 tablet v 6.0.1. The result is that the Btle scan does not detect any advertisements ... though it runs.